# Question about the construction of global Proj

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a Noetherian scheme, and let $\mathscr{S}\in\mathfrak{Qco}(X)$ have the structure of a graded $\mathscr{O}_X$-algebra, i.e. $$\mathscr{S} = \bigoplus_{d\ge 0} \mathscr{S}_d$$ where $\mathscr{S}_d\in\mathfrak{Coh}(X)$ for all $d$, and $\mathscr{S}_0 = \mathscr{O}_X$ and $\mathscr{S}$ is generated by $\mathscr{S}_1$ over $\mathscr{S}_0=\mathscr{O}_X$.

Now, if we set $\mathscr{S}(U) = \Gamma(U,\mathscr{S}\vert_U)$ for any affine open $U$, then Hartshorne asserts that we get a natural morphism $\pi_U:\operatorname{Proj}\mathscr{S}(U)\to U$. But what is this morphism, precisely? I can't see precisely how to construct it, what it is, or why it exists.

Comment: It is not Nötherian, it is Noetherian. (I used to write it using the ö and the friends at MO a long time showed me that it is just wrong)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is that?

Comment: Have you read through the basic Proj construction? On an affine open, $\mathscr{S}(U)$ is a graded $\mathscr{O}_X(U)$-algebra, so it just has the ordinary Proj morphism to the base. The only novelty about global Proj is that the local morphisms are compatible for different affine open sets $U$.